# Compare framewidth and frameheight in Windows explorer search

Tags: windows-10, video, windows-explorer, sorting, dimensions

I am trying to sort a large group of videos (1700). I want to separate videos that have a width that is bigger than the height from videos that have a height bigger than the width.

I found online the term below where you can search for videos of a certain width:

```
framewidth: <=640
```

I tried to change this to work in my favor coming up with the solution below which does not work:

```
framewidth: < frameheight
```

Any ideas how I can sort these videos using the "framewidth" and "frameheight" values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 Pro 64-bit

How to organize your videos:

Explorer does not sort video by dimension. Sort with a batch file, for all video get the width and height, if the width is greater than the height move to `%userprofile%\Desktop\1`. **If video in more than one directory change `dir /b` to `dir /b /s`** Make a text file containing name, width, height, duration, bit rate, and sample rate sorted by name, date, size.

Batch file: Sort using md, cmd, for, dir, ffprobe, set, if, and move:

Must be run in a window with administrative privileges.
Add extensions to `dir /b *.mp4 *.mkv`
**For testing clear desktop of directory named 1**
Works if whitespace in path.
Download [latest](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win64/static/) ffprobe, ffmpeg, and ffplay for Windows 64-bit from ffmpeg.zeranoe.com
Download [test files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IEaDQ3Xl0ljhIUFOTrmdeLDcjI2I6zjw/view?usp=sharing) (5MB) from Google Drive
[How to write a batch file](https://superuser.com/search?tab=votes&q=%20%5Bbatch%5D%20closed%3Ano%20for%20move)

CMD:

```
cmd /V
if not exist "%userprofile%\Desktop\1" md "%userprofile%\Desktop\1"
for /F "tokens=*" %g in ('dir /b *.mp4 *.mkv') do (
for /F %h in ('ffprobe.exe -v error -show_entries stream^=width -of default^=noprint_wrappers^=1:nokey^=1 "%g" 2^>^&1') do set zwidth=%h
for /F %h in ('ffprobe.exe -v error -show_entries stream^=height -of default^=noprint_wrappers^=1:nokey^=1 "%g" 2^>^&1') do set zheight=%h
if !zwidth! gtr !zheight! move /y "%g" "%userprofile%\Desktop\1"
)
rem
```

Script:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if not exist "%userprofile%\Desktop\1" md "%userprofile%\Desktop\1"
for /F "tokens=*" %%g in ('dir /b *.mp4 *.mkv') do (
for /F %%h in ('ffprobe.exe -v error -show_entries stream^=width -of default^=noprint_wrappers^=1:nokey^=1 "%%g" 2^>^&1') do set zwidth=%%h
for /F %%h in ('ffprobe.exe -v error -show_entries stream^=height -of default^=noprint_wrappers^=1:nokey^=1 "%%g" 2^>^&1') do set zheight=%%h
if !zwidth! gtr !zheight! move /y "%%g" "%userprofile%\Desktop\1"
)
rem
```

Test files:

```
input270x480.mp4
input480x270 whitespace.mp4
input480x270.mp4
input270x480.mkv
input480x270 whitespace.mkv
input480x270.mkv
```

Results:

```
input480x270 whitespace.mkv
input480x270 whitespace.mp4
input480x270.mkv
input480x270.mp4
```

Make a text file containing name, width, height, duration, bit rate, sample rate sorted by name, date, size:

CMD:

```
(
echo Sort by name
echo %date%
echo%time%
echo.)> sortbyname.txt
for /F "tokens=*" %g in ('dir /b *.mp4 *.mkv') do (
echo %g
echo Video Stream0:
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream^=width,height,duration,bit_rate -of default^=noprint_wrappers^=1 "%g"
echo Audio Stream0:
ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream^=duration,bit_rate,sample_rate -of default^=noprint_wrappers^=1 "%g"    
echo.
)>> sortbyname.txt

(
echo Sort new to old 
echo %date% 
echo%time% 
echo.)> sortNewToOld.txt 
for /F "tokens=*" %g in ('dir /b /o-d *.mp4 *.mkv') do (
echo %g
echo Video Stream0:
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream^=width,height,duration,bit_rate -of default^=noprint_wrappers^=1 "%g"
echo Audio Stream0:
ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream^=duration,bit_rate,sample_rate -of default^=noprint_wrappers^=1 "%g"    
echo.
)>> sortNewToOld.txt

(
echo Sort large to small 
echo %date% 
echo%time% 
echo.)> sortLargeToSmall.txt
for /F "tokens=*" %g in ('dir /b /o-s *.mp4 *.mkv') do (
echo %g
echo Video Stream0:
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream^=width,height,duration,bit_rate -of default^=noprint_wrappers^=1 "%g"
echo Audio Stream0:
ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream^=duration,bit_rate,sample_rate -of default^=noprint_wrappers^=1 "%g"    
echo.
)>> sortLargeToSmall.txt
rem
```

Script:

```
(
echo Sort by name
echo %date%
echo%time%
echo.)> sortbyname.txt
for /F "tokens=*" %%g in ('dir /b /a-d *.mp4 *.mkv') do (
echo %%g
echo Video Stream0:
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream^=width,height,duration,bit_rate -of default^=noprint_wrappers^=1 "%%g"
echo Audio Stream0:
ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream^=duration,bit_rate,sample_rate -of default^=noprint_wrappers^=1 "%%g"    
echo.
)>> sortbyname.txt

(
echo Sort new to old 
echo %date% 
echo%time% 
echo.)> sortNewToOld.txt 
for /F "tokens=*" %%g in ('dir /b /o-d *.mp4 *.mkv') do (
echo %%g
echo Video Stream0:
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream^=width,height,duration,bit_rate -of default^=noprint_wrappers^=1 "%%g"
echo Audio Stream0:
ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream^=duration,bit_rate,sample_rate -of default^=noprint_wrappers^=1 "%%g"    
echo.
)>> sortNewToOld.txt

(
echo Sort large to small 
echo %date% 
echo%time% 
echo.)> sortLargeToSmall.txt
for /F "tokens=*" %%g in ('dir /b /o-s *.mp4 *.mkv') do (
echo %%g
echo Video Stream0:
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream^=width,height,duration,bit_rate -of default^=noprint_wrappers^=1 "%%g"
echo Audio Stream0:
ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream^=duration,bit_rate,sample_rate -of default^=noprint_wrappers^=1 "%%g"    
echo.
)>> sortLargeToSmall.txt
rem
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Forgot about this post

Answer (score 0):

Windows Explorer is not the right tool for such operations.
PowerShell is much more suitable.

You could use the following PowerShell script to move all images whose
width is less-than the height to another folder:

```
$image = New-Object -ComObject Wia.ImageFile
foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem "C:\source\folder" | Where-Object Extension -In ".jpg", ".bmp", ".png") {
    $image.LoadFile($item.fullname)
    if ($image.Width -lt $image.Height) {
        Move-Item -LiteralPath $item.FullName -Destination "C:\target\folder"
    }
}
```

You could run this script directly from PowerShell or from the Command Prompt:

```
powershell -File script.ps1 -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Comment: Thank you for this!